# Track changes option in pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex

Is their any track changes option available in LaTex, similar to word. If some other person want to mark comments in my LaTex document, is that possible?

Comment: The nice thing about TeX is that source code is text only.  Thus, even if you just save copies of versions as you go along a project, the actual changes are easily recovered with a `diff` between the files.  There are some very nice `diff` utilities available these days.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to track changes in latex. 
Because it is basically just code, you can use a sourcecode tracking tool like git.

As a single person writing a document, I found [latexdiff](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff) useful. It allows you to create a modified document and compare it to another (original) document. The script then creates a diff-document that, when compiled, gives you word like syntax highlighting with red striked out text and blue added text e.g.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general - if you are working with several people on the same document, it can be helpful to use a version management system (like SVN or Git). It did this for one of my last scientific proposals.

Furthermore, you could have a look at online tools like

https://www.writelatex.com/